# Exporting AIFF to AAC using Apple's AVFoundationExporter sample code gets me something slightly broken

Tags: swift, avfoundation, core-audio, aac, aiff

I've downloaded Apple's sample code AVFoundationExporter (available from the Apple dev site). The title of the project is "AVFoundationExporter: Exporting and Transcoding Movies", but I'm trying to use it to change an AIFF file to an AAC (M4A) file.

On the desktop, I have a file "testfile.aiff". I invoke it with the command...

```
AVFoundationExporter "/Users/rbell/Desktop/testfile.aiff" "/Users/rbell/Desktop/testfile.m4a" -preset AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A -f public.mpeg-4-audio"
```

(or just [AVFoundationExporter "/Users/rbell/Desktop/testfile.aiff" "/Users/rbell/Desktop/testfile.m4a"])

... I do indeed get a file called "testfile.m4a" on my desktop. And I can indeed play it using Finder's spacebar preview, or using QuickTime.

However, I cannot open it with or import it into iTunes. It simply won't go. I can open the .aiff file just fine, and it plays happily. But when I try to force the .m4a file to "Open in... iTunes", iTunes opens and nothing happens. The .m4a file does not appear in iTunes anywhere.

I tried changing the line

```
var destinationFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie
```

to

```
var destinationFileType = AVFileTypeAppleM4A
```

And it now fails with

> error: Operation Stopped: The operation is not supported for this
>   media.. Program ended with exit code: 1

I've fiddled a lot of settings, and nothing seems to work. The -inject-metadata flag doesn't make any difference. Neither does using a -preset. -fileType com.apple.m4a-audio doesn't help. The strange thing is that I really do get the file I want. It just doesn't work properly. If I open my "testfile.m4a" file in QuickTime and export it again, then I end up with an .m4a file with a different bitrate, but this one does open in iTunes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file type `public.mpeg-4-audio` (from `kUTTypeMPEG4Audio`?) is wrong. You need `com.apple.m4a-audio` (which corresponds to `AVFileTypeAppleM4A`).

Don't forget to remove the existing `m4a` file first!

So your command should be

```
rm -f out.m4a  # AVFoundation doesn't like overwriting existing files.
AVFoundationExporter in.aiff out.m4a -preset AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A -f public.mpeg-4-audio
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the help. But... This does indeed produce the expected .m4a file, which does actually play if you double-click on it (and if you select it and hit spacebar). But when I right click on it and say "Open in > iTunes", iTunes opens but the .m4a file doesn't import. It doesn't play either. There is a line in main.swift that reads: "var destinationFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie". If I change that to "var destinationFileType = AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A" (trying to match the m4a preset), then I get a crash, with the following:

Comment: 2016-02-15 19:15:51.915 AVFoundationExporter[9371:1120595] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid output file type'

Comment: (Mac OS X 10.11.3 and iTunes 12.3.2.35, in case it matters)

Comment: wait, why are you changing the code when you can pass those things as arguments to the command line tool? can you a) try again with an unmodified `AVFoundationExporter` and b) provide a link to an offending m4a file?